# B2B Template (LWR) - "globalStyles.css" style

Tags: css, stylesheets, global

What is the best way to include a "globalStyles.css" style so it can be loaded at site level.
I tried to include this "globalStyles.css" in the static resources and then reference it in the head tag but it did not work.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{ basePath }/sfsites/c/resource/globalStyles/globalStyles.css?{ versionKey }" />`

Note: I uploaded the style directly in static resources and not inside a .zip file

Maybe I'm doing this wrong and there is a better way, I'm quite new to "B2B Template (LWR)"